# Swift: can't find glProgramParameteriEXT

Tags: macos, swift

Im trying to move from *Objective-C* to *swift* but can't seem to figure out how to call OpenGL extension functions. Normally I would need to include `OpenGL/glext.h`.

Where is that hiding in swift (import OpenGL, GLKit is not enough)??

```
glProgramParameteriEXT(program,GL_GEOMETRY_INPUT_TYPE_EXT , GL_TRIANGLES)
```

Comment: Swift doesn't really work well with OpenGL, there's an extension: [SwiftGL](https://github.com/sbennett912/SwiftGL) which may help you with that though

Comment: FYI: Apple recommends that you use [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/).